# Unable to inject bean in OncePerRequestFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm not being able to inject beans into my `OncePerRequestFilter`. Here's the `XHeaderAuthenticationFilter`:

```java
@Component
public class XHeaderAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  public XHeaderAuthenticationFilter() {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
  }

  @Autowired private JwtUtils jwtUtils; // null
  @Autowired private UserService userService; // null

  @Override
  @SneakyThrows
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {

    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    if (new AntPathMatcher().match("/getToken", path)
        || HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    String jwt = parseJwt(request);
    jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt); // NullPointerException here

    // ...

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

And here the registration part:

```java
  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new XHeaderAuthenticationFilter());
    registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return registrationBean;
  }
```

I set `enabled` to false as the filter was getting called multiple times. I'm new to SpringSecurity and need much exposure to the concept. I also want to add the configuration part just in case I did something wrong there:

```java
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/getToken")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
            new XHeaderAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
```

There are a lot of fixes for this issue but none worked for me. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

### Update 1

Including JwtUtils:

```java
@Component
public class JwtUtils {

  @Value("${security.jwtSecret}")
  private String jwtSecret;

  @Value("${security.jwtExpirationMs}")
  private int jwtExpirationMs;

  public String getJWTToken(String username) {}

  public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {}

  public Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {}
}
```

and UserService:

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public User saveUser(UserModel userModel) {}

  @Override
  public UserModel findUserByEmail(String email) {}

  @Override
  public UserListViewResponse findAllUsers(Specification<User> userSpecification, Pageable paging) {}

  @Override
  public UserModel deleteUser(String email) {}

  private UserListViewResponse populateUserListViewResponse(Page<User> pagedResult) {}

  private List<User> filterAdmins(List<User> userEntityList) {}
```

Comment: why you insert `XHeaderAuthenticationFilter` one time using `FilterRegistrationBean` and another time using `addFilterBefore`?

Comment: @hatefalipoor I've included the beans. I have added using FilterRegistrationBean because the filter was getting called multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you register `XHeaderAuthenticationFilter` in `FilterRegistrationBean` causes the problem because you yourself create the `XHeaderAuthenticationFilter` with `new` not `Spring` with all resolving DI stuff. change your code like:

```
@Autowired
XHeaderAuthenticationFilter xHeaderAuthenticationFilter;

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(xHeaderAuthenticationFilter);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Same applies if you want to register `XHeaderAuthenticationFilter` using `addFilterBefore`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether this will be relevant to you but I would avoid making your onceperrequest filters a bean.

We had a problem which took us one week to figure out that for multiple security configurations which are mapped to specific antMatchers, adding a bean filter to one security chain would also trigger the filter in another security chain. Even with with the addFilter line commented! We never called addFilter in our code yet this filter was still picked up.

Comment: If you want to do injection they need to be a bean, there is one thing you need to take care of (and this is mentioned in the documentation as well, but who reads that) that you need a `FilterRegistrationBean` if you use this only in your security filter chain.

Comment: ahh so you would define a filterregistrationbean and add filters there, map them to urls without needing to call addFilter in the filterchain?

Comment: No. You would disable them with the `FilterRegistationBean` so that they don't get added to the regular filter chain. It is just the other way around.